# angular $http not sending any value into server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

i'm trying to send JSON data into server, and want to get response text from server.

this is my code :

```
app.directive("registerSection",['$http',function($http){
  return{
    restrict : "E",
    templateUrl : "view/register-section.html",
    controller : function(){
      this.regdata = {};
      this.addData = function(){
        // Send Data
        $http({method:'POST',url:'http://url.com/account/register',data:JSON.stringify(this.regdata)}).then(function(dt){
          alert(JSON.stringify(dt));
        },function(dt){
        alert(JSON.stringify(dt));
        });
      };
    },
    controllerAs : "reg"
  };
}]);
```

this is the html code :

```
<form name="registerForm" ng-submit="registerForm.$valid && reg.addData()" novalidate>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="reg.regdata.name" placeholder="Your Name" required><br />
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="reg.regdata.email" placeholder="Your Email" required><br />
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="reg.regdata.password" placeholder="Your Password" required><br />
<p>{{reg.regdata}}</p>
<button type="submit">Register</button>
```

i've already see the angular docs, and the server still not getting any values from client.
i've see the same problem in stack overflow but still it doesn't have any answer for this problem.

sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Comment: You've assigned `this.addData` to be the function that makes the request but where are you calling that function?

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Don't run your data through `JSON.stringify`, Angular does that for you already. A simple `$http.post('http://url.com/account/register', this.regdata)` should suffice

Comment: @Phil - i'm already tried not to use `JSON.stringify` but there's no different with / without using that

Comment: Your controller in your directive does not have access to the scope. I would suggest injecting $scope to the controller and then change `this` to $scope.

Comment: @ABr - adding scope just will give me an error `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20registerSectionDirective` . to be honest, i don't understand what's scope and what is scope function. i;ve read the doc but i don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by the way you add the data to your $http call.
You could try to change your controller function as follow:

```
controller : function(){
  this.regdata = {};

  //Send Data
  this.addData = function(){
    var url = 'http://url.com/account/register';
    $http.post(url, this.regdata).then(function(dt){
      console.log(dt);
    },function(dt){
    console.log(dt);
    });
  };
}
```

You do not have to stringify since the $http service will do that for you.

Note: The url is not working for me, so I cannot test that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.myfun = function(id){

    data = "id="+id;
    $http.post("http://192.168.1.52/Angularjs/responce.php?get=true", data ,{headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function (response) {

        $scope.data1 = response;

        $scope.formid= $scope.data1[0].id;
        $scope.fName = $scope.data1[0].firstname;
        $scope.lName = $scope.data1[0].lastname;

        $scope.passw1 = $scope.data1[0].password;
        $scope.passw2 = $scope.data1[0].password;


        }
    );  };
```

This Is working For Me

Comment: it's not a JSON, i've already trying that. it's connected but not send any values

Comment: for sending values you have to specify header type. in my codeigniter project when i send through header type then i am able to receive the value at my controller.